# load file with new line characters

Tags: java

here is my code, to load the content as a byte, then convert the integer to hex values:

```
    try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        while ((byteRead = is.read()) != -1) {
            //System.out.print(((char) byteRead).charAt(0));
            String temp = Character.toString((char) byteRead);
            ta.append(Character.toString((char) byteRead));
            System.out.print(Character.toString((char) byteRead));

            ta2.append(Integer.toHexString(byteRead) + " ");

        }
    }
```

the output: 41 42 43 d a 31 32 33

but it seems that, the new line character can't be read, i know the new line character hex value is "0A", how do i fix it?

Comment: http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/space.html

Answer (score 2):

No, you *are* reading the line break - that's that the "d" followed by "a" is - carriage return followed by line feed ("\r\n").

However, you're currently *assuming* that the file is in ISO-8859-1. To read text files, you should almost always use a `Reader` instead of reading bytes directly from a stream. I would suggest using `InputStreamReader`, specifying the encoding explicitly. For example:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

You might also want to wrap the reader in a `BufferedReader`, which makes it easy to read lines. Alternatively, I can thoroughly recommend the utility classes in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) (particularly [`CharStreams`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html)), which make it easier to work with files like this.

Comment: but how to make changes to the file force the output print "0A"?

Comment: @hkinterview: That's nothing to do with reading files - that's the conversion of the byte value 10 to hex. Is that what your question is really about: converting bytes to hex with padding?